# Touchpad on laptop not working

Tags: laptop, touchpad

How can I get the touchpad on my laptop to work? I have a Samsung 700z3a laptop. The touchpad used to work until I reinstalled windows 7. I installed the driver on here
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP700Z3A-S06US
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple drivers listed on the page you linked. Make sure you get the correct (Windows 7) driver.

Alternatively, try reading here, see if any of those suggestions help:

[Sudden touchpad failure on Samsung 700G7C](https://superuser.com/questions/797109/sudden-touchpad-failure-on-samsung-700g7c?rq=1)